# extracting fields from JSON output using python

Tags: python, json

Using Python, how can I extract the field RestartRowID to a variable?:

```
{
  "emp": [
     {

      "id": "",
      "company": "y",
      "address": "y",
      "mobile no": 0,
      "name": 0
    }
  ],
  "RestartRowID": "0x0000000000133a09"
}
```

something like :

```
id = emp["RestartRowID"]
print (id)
```

Thanks..

Comment: What is wrong with your code ? Have you any errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert the json data to dictionary

```
data_dict=json.loads(<jsondata>)
```

You can get your required answer using data_dict['RestartRowID']

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
>>> import json
>>> a = '''{
...   "emp": [
...      {
... 
...       "id": "",
...       "company": "y",
...       "address": "y",
...       "mobile no": 0,
...       "name": 0
...     }
...   ],
...   "RestartRowID": "0x0000000000133a09"
... }'''
>>> data = json.loads(a)
>>> data['RestartRowID']
u'0x0000000000133a09'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`emp` and `RestartRowID` are on the same level so you should be extracting one from the other.

```
data = {
  "emp": [
     {

      "id": "",
      "company": "y",
      "address": "y",
      "mobile no": 0,
      "name": 0
    }
  ],
  "RestartRowID": "0x0000000000133a09"
}
```

Output:

```
In [264]: id = data["RestartRowID"]

In [265]: id
Out[265]: '0x0000000000133a09'
```